# How to populate Titan with example data sets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin, rexster

I am following the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.html) on how to run [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/) with [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) as a storage backend. There seem to be a lot of ways to query my graphs ([Gremlin](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/hadoop-gremlin-cli.html) CLI, [Rexster](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/The-Dog-House) via JSON and Web UI). My `rexster.xml` [configuration](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Rexster-Configuration) [file](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/0.5.4/src/test/resources/rexster-local.xml) references a `graph-name` called "v054".

**But how do I actually persist a graph to the storage layer and update it?**

From my `rexster.xml`:

```
<graph-name>v054</graph-name>
<graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
<graph-location>/tmp/titan</graph-location>
<graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
```

Rexster Web UI:

[image: Screenshot from Rexster]

**Update 1**

To see the DynamoDB tables created to store the Titan graphs, ensure DynamoDB local is started using the `-sharedDb` flag (see documentation). This is not enforced by the `start-dynamodb-local` profile yet. Replace the `-inMemory` flag by `-shared` in your `pom.xml`.

```
    <profile>
        <id>start-dynamodb-local</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>java</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <!-- left out other arguments for brevity .. -->
                                    <argument>-sharedDb</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
```

Once you run DynamoDB Local with `-sharedDb`, you will see the following tables created:

```
{
  "TableNames": [
    "v054_edgestore",
    "v054_graphindex",
    "v054_system_properties",
    "v054_systemlog",
    "v054_titan_ids",
    "v054_txlog"
  ]
}
```

**Update 2**

I am able to obtain a reference to my graph by running the commands mentioned under [step 5 in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html#Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.title). However, I had to use the fully-qualified name of `TitanFactory.open()` (see below). See [this Github issue](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/96) for more information.

```
gremlin> conf = new BaseConfiguration()
gremlin> conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint", "http://localhost:4567")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("index.search.backend", "elasticsearch")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("index.search.directory", "/tmp/searchindex")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("index.search.elasticsearch.client-only", "false")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode", "true")
gremlin> conf.setProperty("index.search.elasticsearch.interface", "NODE")
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open(conf)
==>javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TitanFactory for class: Script12
gremlin> g = com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(conf)
==>titangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted a screenshot of the Rexster Doghouse. It embeds a Gremlin Shell. Click on the Gremlin button on the top, and start modifying your new graph with Gremlin scripts. See [the project readme](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/0.5.4/README.md) for examples of gremlin commands to add graph data, and the [gremlin docs here](https://github.com/spmallette/GremlinDocs) for more examples. Remember to call g.commit() when creating your own graph data (not using the sample graph data like the Marvel data set or the graph of the gods.

Comment: But how do I actually reference my `v054` graph in the gremlin console? Evaluating `v054` in the console results in a `MissingPropertyException`. But I can evaluate (and commit) another graph `g`. However, even after running `g.commit()`, I am not seeing any DynamoDB local tables getting created when I am trying to list them with the [Javascript Shell](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.html#Tools.DynamoDBLocal.Shell).

Comment: You mention a good point. You need to make sure that the region and credential in your DynamoDB Local Shell script requests are the same as the selected region and credential for the DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan as used in Rexster. It may be easier to use the `-shared flag` when starting DynamoDB Local, that way, the same tables in the Local instance will be used, regardless of your region/credential setting.

Comment: The flag is `-sharedDb` as per the docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html

Comment: Right, but if that is the case, shouldn't the `start-dynamodb-local` profile in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/0.5.4/pom.xml) use `-sharedDB` as well? Right now it is only using `-inMemory`. And even then, how can I reference the default `v054` Titan DB graph in the Gremlin console?

Comment: I made the [change](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/0.5.4/pom.xml#L272) to pom.xml to use `-sharedDb` yesterday.